# JNDI JBOSS autocommit along with Spring JDBC Template

Tags: java, spring, jboss, datasource

Using JBOSS EAP 6.2 as server, and application is build on Spring framework
The connection autocommit is set to 'false'.

But Still, the transaction is committed automatically, and I get to know from these two scenarios :
1. when an application exception is thrown, I'm asking to rollback, but it is getting committed
2. I am not putting `@Transactional` on certain methods, because I do not want them to do a commit,
but that is also autocommitted[the method insert data to temp table]

> JBOSS Configuration for datasource

Reference: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_BRMS_Platform/5/html/BRMS_Administrator_Guide/Configuring_a_Datasource_for_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform_6.html

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.1">
             <datasources>
               <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc/myapp" pool-name="myapp-ds" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@server1:1521/MDBA1</connection-url>
                    <connection-property name="autoCommit">false</connection-property>
                    <driver>ojdbc6-11.2.0.4</driver>
                    <new-connection-sql>select * from dual</new-connection-sql>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>user1</user-name>
                        <password>user1</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1 from dual</check-valid-connection-sql>
                        <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                        <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
               </datasource> 
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="ojdbc6-11.2.0.4" module="com.oracle">
                        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</xa-datasource-class>
                        <!-- <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</xa-datasource-class> -->
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

> Spring Configuration

```
<jee:jndi-lookup  id="oracleDataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc/myapp"/>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"
        p:dataSource-ref="oracleDataSource" />

<!-- Enable Annotation based Declarative Transaction Management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
        p:dataSource-ref="oracleDataSource">
</bean>

<tx:advice id="defaultTxAdvice">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="readOnlyMethods*" read-only="true" />
            <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Exception" />
        </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

> Java methods

(1)
// This is having `@Transactional`, hence understanding is that, if we get an exception, 
//transaction will be rolledback, else it will be committed.

```
@Transactional
public void updateStudent(String name) throws DBException {

try{
   // use jdbc template to call the stored procedure
   // if stored procedure out param returns a value of 'false' then throw exception as we dont want to commit this data.
} catch(Exception ex) {
    throw new DBException();
  }
}
```

(2)
// This does **NOT** have `@Transactional` , hence understanding is that this will never be committed

```
public String readOnlyMethodsUpdateEmployee(String name) throws DBException {

try{
   // use jdbc template to call the stored procedure
   // the stored procedure tries to update the EmployeeName 
   // return the stored procedure output param value. dont commit anything. [To test autocommit]
} catch(Exception ex) {
   //log it
  }
}
```

**Problem:**

In both the above said cases, the transaction is getting committed, which basically means 
the `<connection-property name="autoCommit">false</connection-property>` in JBOSS configuration
is not working. Why is not working? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is working however your code is breaking proper tx management. In case 1 you are catching and converting the exception, however you haven't specified `rollbackFor=DBException.class` in your `@Transactional`. Spring will only rollback `RuntimeException`s or `Error`s not checked exceptions. Your second scenarion will auto commit after the query execution this is the default behavior of the `JdbcTemplate` and has nothing to do with auto commit on your connection or not. Also in your second case if you would use `@Transactional` it wouldn't work either because you are catching the exception.

Comment: Your reply resolved my question.Please post as answer for me to mark the question as answered. your reply is much informative, but in case 1, `DB exception` actually `extends RunTimeException` hence, inline with your statement, I need not say explicit `rollbackFor`, and `@Transactional` is sufficient.  I also acknowledge the fact that `autocommit=true` need to be set, and based on `@Transactional `annotation and throwing exception, Spring will either commit or rollback a transaction. [If we set `autocommit` as `false`, Spring cannot commit a transaction hence that is not the correct approach].

Comment: auto commit shouldn't be `true` also if it is that value (and you have configured transactions correctly) the transaction management will set it to `false` and reset it after the transaction completed.